# 413 http error on image upload in iis6

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis-6

I keep getting a 413 error "Entity too large" when uploading images (particular image is a 275kb PNG) with an asp.net form.  I have thoroughly researched this, and changed:

AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed to 1000000 as suggested here- http://www.banmanpro.com/support2/File_Upload_limits.asp

UploadReadAheadSize to 1000000 as suggested here- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737382.aspx

web.config on the directory containing the script has a maxRequestLength of 1550000

None of these solved the problem.  Can someone else help me please?  I have tested this on a development site on another server and the script works fine, so it doesn't seem to be script related.

Comment: Does a smaller file upload successfully?  (<200K)  

How are you uploading the file?  Are you using the FileUpLoad control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cscript adsutil.vbs set w3svc/1/uploadreadaheadsize 204800
```

It appears that when using 3rd party upload controls, and I assuming you are, IIS has an issue passing the data to the ISAPI extensions. The above command will set the UploadReadAheadSize to 204800KB. You may need to adjust the set parameters to match the web ID you are on. Hopefully you have access to the server.

Read more about it [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737382.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I need this today, the command line above dont work for me, so I found this:

**IIS 7**:
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347568(v=vs.90).aspx

**uploadReadAheadSize**

Specifies the number of bytes that a Web server will read into a buffer and pass
to an ISAPI extension or module.
This occurs once per client request.
The ISAPI extension or module receives any additional data directly from the client.
The value must be between 0 and 2147483647.

The default value is 49152/48k.

**Solution**

1. Stop IIS
2. Edit the file:
   C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
   set serverRuntime overrideModeDefault param to allow.
3. Edit the file:
   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config
   set uploadReadAheadSize to new value.
4. Restart IIS

**applicationHost.config**

```
<section name="serverRuntime" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

**web.config**

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <serverRuntime maxRequestEntityAllowed="2072576000" uploadReadAheadSize="536870912"/>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```