# uploadify on asp net mvc and iis 7.5 fails with some files

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, iis, uploadify

Some files are uploaded other don´t
I thought it was a upload size limit so I added to my web.config

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000" maxUrl="32768" maxQueryString="32768" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

and as you can see below in the uploadfy:

```
'fileSizeLimit' : 500000
```

That is all I need to accept files <= 500MB
How can I find the reason for this failure?

**ERROR:**

```
errorCode: 200
errorMsg: 413
errorString: HTTP 413 Error
```

**UPLOADFY:**

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'debug': true,
        'swf': '../../Components/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader': '/Operacao/Upload',
        'auto': false,
        'buttonImage': '../../Images/uploadify/importar.jpg',
        'buttonClass': 'uploadifyBtn',
        'width': '210',
        'height': '21',
        'fileSizeLimit' : 500000,
        'onUploadStart' : function(file) {
            //return alert('Starting to upload ' + file.name);
        },
        'onFallback': function () {
            alert('Versão do flash não compativel com o sistema de upload. Favor contactar o administrador do sistema!');
        },
        'onUploadError' : function(file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString) {
            alert('O arquivo ' + file.name + ' não pode ser importado: ' + errorCode + ' - ' + errorMsg + ' - ' + errorString);
        },
        'onSelectError': function () {
            alert('Você não tem permissão para acessar o arquivo: "' + file.name + '" ou o arquivo está corrompido. Favor contactar o administrador do sistema.');
        },
        'onUploadSuccess': function (file, data, response) {
            //alert(data);
            if (data == 'true') {
                isOk = true;
                success('true');
            } else {
                success('false');
                isOk = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried taking a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467355/413-http-error-on-image-upload-in-iis6) answer?

> Try this:
>
> `cscript adsutil.vbs set w3svc/1/uploadreadaheadsize 204800`
>
> It appears that when using 3rd party upload controls, and I assuming
>   you are, IIS has an issue passing the data to the ISAPI extensions.
>   The above command will set the UploadReadAheadSize to 204800KB. You
>   may need to adjust the set parameters to match the web ID you are on.
>   Hopefully you have access to the server.
>
> Read more about it
>   [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737382.aspx).

Comment: I need that configured on web.config xml file. I have added <location path="gedaiapp">
   <system.webServer>
      <serverRuntime enabled="true" maxRequestEntityAllowed="524288000" />
   </system.webServer>
</location> to my xml but doing that my js files are not loaded properly... don´t know why. I am getting Internal Server Error